# What are the differences between the volatile in c# and java?

Tags: c#, java, multithreading, memory-optimization

In some .net documentation I have read this is how the compiler handles volatile:

- *"Reading from a volatile or using the Thread.VolatileRead method is logically an acquire fence"
- "Writing to a volatile or using the Thread.VolatileWrite method is logically a release fence" *

These fences apply at both complier and architecture level.

Of course the main difference in VC++ is that the fence is only applied at complier level.

So my question is, what are the memory reordering prevention semantics of volatile in Java?

Conversion:

Fence  = Barrier
Barrier = Fence

References:

Joe Duffy (Concurrent Programming on Windows)

Comment: You should find the answer in the JLS (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), although of course the vocabulary will differ

Comment: None that I'm aware of; a volatile read in Java is equivalent to an acquire, a write to a release - same as for the CLR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, the `javac` compiler does next to nothing with volatile.  It doesn't re-order statements and does almost no optimisation.

The JIT on the other hand can do quite a bit of optimisation and re-ordering.

The important features of `volatile` are;

- read/write access cannot be optimise away
- any write which occurs before a volatile write has to occur before the write.
- any read which occurs after a volatile read, must occur after the read.

Comment: The meaning is very critical. For example, let's say you have 3 threads using the same variable, and you have 3 processors. volatile would force an update of the variable value from one processor to the other two.

Comment: @lionheart That could happen anyway; however, the JIT is free to inline a variable it determines that thread isn't altering, e.g. it tends to do this with `boolean` easily, so it might never read a change another thread makes.